# Proving analycity of two complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

We have :

a) $x^2-y^2+2ixy$

and

b) $x^2+y^2+y-2ix$

By Cauchy-Riemann equations, $u_x=v_y$ and $-v_x=u_y$ we obtain:

a) $u_x= 2x$, $v_y=2ix$, $-v_x=-2iy$, $u_y=-2y$

b) $u_x= 2x$, $v_y=0$, $-v_x=2i$, $u_y=2y+1$

Clearly, $u_x\ne v_y$ and $-v_x\ne u_y$ for both cases.

**Still a) should be analytic.**

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u$ and $v$ are the real and imaginary parts of the functions, respectively. So, for (a),
$$ u(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$$
$$ v(x,y) = 2xy$$
So $u_x = 2x, v_y = 2x$, and $u_y = -2y, -v_x = -2y$.

I'll leave the second one for you to try again.

Comment: For a) I got $u_x=2x, u_y=-2y$ and $v_y=2x$ and $-v_x=2y$. Fr the second, I got  $u_x=2x, u_y=2y+1$ and $v_y=1$ and $-v_x=0$, so that one is non-analytic.

Comment: $u$ and $v$ should both be real-valued functions – so no $i$ should appear anywhere. So in the second one, $v=-2x$, because it's the imaginary part. You're right that it's not analytic, but your working isn't quite right.

Comment: Ok! Thanks! Got it